# PSVR + Playstation 4 Pro + UHD TV ⇒ blackouts

Tags: ps4, playstation-vr

Since the beginning I had blackouts both on my UHD TV and on the displays of the PSVR headset when using the PlayStation VR with the PlayStation 4 Pro.

Looks like others also suffer from [this problem](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/01/11/playstation_4_pro_psvr_headset_audio_vision_loss/) and it also seems it is somehow Pro specific, as it does not seem to happen with plain PS4. I tried lots of things like reducing HDCP to 1.4 or setting the resolution explicitly to HD (although UHD doesn’t seem to be passed through the PSVR processor box anyway). I even replaced the whole PSVR which didn’t help either.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

After trying everything which came to my mind for another bunch of hours, I finally found a workaround, which works for me.

My TV has several HDMI ports, some of them capable of 4K, some only capable of HD. I always had the PS4Pro/PSVR combo plugged into a 4K port, because initially I had in mind that the PlayStation 4 Pro is capable of producing 4K.

**So what I did now is plugging to a HDMI port on my TV which is plain HD (non-4k, non-UHD). This seems to solve (or rather workaround) the blackout problem.** As the PSVR processor box cannot pass 4K anyway (which I did not know from the start), this is not an additional drawback.

Comment: The processor box can indeed pass through 4k but not HDR. 4K is working fine for me but for HDR I need to plug the PS4 directly into the TV. The HDR issue is fixed in the v2 version of the processor box but unfortunately this is not sold without the headset.

Comment: My TV is not capable of HDR. So my issue seems to be independent of that.